# Solution explanation Durrett probability 5th edition exercise 2.3.12

Tags: probability, proof-explanation

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be a sequence of random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ where $\Omega$ is a countable set and $\mathcal{F}$ consists of all subsets of $\Omega$. Show $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability implies $X_n \rightarrow X$ a.s.

Here is the solution from the book: We can pick $\delta_n \rightarrow 0$ so that $P(|X_n-X|>\delta_n) \rightarrow 0$. Let $\omega \in \Omega$ with $P(\omega)=p>0$. For large $n$ we have $P(|X_n-X|>\delta_n)  \leq p/2$ so $|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)| \leq \delta_n \rightarrow 0$. If $\Omega_0=\{\omega:P(\{w\})>0\}$ then $P(\Omega_0)=1$ and done.

I don't follow the argument, starting "For large $n$ we have $P(|X_n-X|>\delta_n)  \leq p/2$ so $|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)| \leq \delta_n \rightarrow 0$.". Can someone walk me through? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A_n$ be the set $\{\lvert X_n-X\rvert>\delta_n\}$ and $A=\{\omega\}$. Since $\mathbb P\left(A_n\right)\leqslant p/2<\mathbb P(A)$, we know that the inclusion $A\subseteq A_n$ cannot take place. Therefore, $\omega$ belongs to the complement of $A_n$, which precisely means the inequality $\lvert X_n\left(\omega\right)-X\left(\omega\right)\rvert\leqslant \delta_n$.